# Excel: how to add cells to named range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I have a named range for 3 cells in excel 2003
I need to insert 1 more cell into this named range

how do I achieve this in excel 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert > Name > Define
Find the name in the list, click on it and then change the definition in the "relates to" box (so in you rcase change the row or column number to increase the range)
Click OK to finish

Answer (score 8):

For Office 07, click on the Formulas tab, then "Name Manager".
You should now see a list of all named ranges you have in this workbook.
Click on any one of them and you can change the range at the bottom (don't forget to save)

Cheers.