# How to reference same cell in previous sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to reference a cell in another sheet in Excel, but I'd like to know if there's some way to automate this process, such that if I duplicate a sheet, it will update its references to the previous sheet in sequence.

For example, let's say sheet `n` has a cell that references a cell in sheet `n-1`. If I have sheets 1, 2, and 3, I want the cell in 3 to reference a cell in 2. Then, if I duplicate 3 (making Sheet4), I want the same cell in 4 to reference the cell in 3.

Ordinarily, I'd have the cell in Sheet3 read, `'Sheet2'!A1`. Then, if I duplicate Sheet3 to make Sheet4, I'd have to go into that same cell on Sheet4 and change it from `'Sheet2'!A1` to `'Sheet3'!A1`. I'd rather have this change done automatically when I duplicate the sheet.

Is there a way to automate this process rather than having to do it by hand? I'm currently using Excel 2013 preview but I also have Excel 2012.

Comment: Nevermind, found my solution right here: http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip63.htm . Turns out macros are extremely powerful! :)

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question, so that the rest of the world can benifit as well!!

Comment: I did, check my comment above.

Comment: You've answered it as a comment. If you answer it as an answer, people tend to notice it better and can benefit from it.

Comment: So, please use the **answer your question** button below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution right here: [j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip63.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20150627010615/http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip63.htm) . Turns out macros are extremely powerful! :)

You can create a function called sheetoffset in VBA to do this

```
Function SHEETOFFSET(offset, Ref)
'   Returns cell contents at Ref, in sheet offset
    Application.Volatile
    With Application.Caller.Parent
        SHEETOFFSET = .Parent.Sheets(.Index + offset) _
         .Range(Ref.Address).Value
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't go through the entire J-walk document you posted but this is a pretty easy way to hard-code it. It uses the sheet's index to reference cells from other sheets instead of the sheet's name, so it doesn't matter if a sheet is renamed or if you don't know what the next sheet's name will be.

```
Function prevSheet()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

  i = ActiveSheet.Index             ' Obtain current sheet index
  j = i - 1                         ' Determine the previous sheet's index
  oldValue = Sheets(j).Range("A1")  ' Obtain value from prev sheet's A1 cell 
  
  newValue =  oldValue + 1          ' Random operation to alter prev sheet's value
  Range("A1") = newValue            ' Display the new value on current sheet's A1 cell

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on any worksheet tab and click on "VIEW CODE"

Place the following code into MODULE 1. (if it's not there just click INSERT and MODULE)

Code

```
Function oldsheet(rng As Variant)
    Prevsn = "Sheet" & Val(Mid(ActiveSheet.CodeName, 6, (Len(ActiveSheet.CodeName) - 5))) - 1
    With Sheets(Prevsn)
        oldsheet = .Range(rng)
    End With
End Function
```

And the new sheet the following formula

```
=oldsheet("J30")
```

Posted as is from link just in case it gets deleted.

Ref pulled from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/399317-formula-referencing-previous-sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

Use in cell like
=Prev(J30)

```
Function Prev(ByRef r As Range) As Variant
Application.Volatile
Prev = r.Parent.Previous.Range(r.Address).Value
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a defined name and formula.  Although you're not adding any VBA code it will require saving the file with a macro compatible file type such as .xlsm.

Create a defined name.  Name it `wsNamesArray` and in the "Refers To" box enter the following:

### First, Create Two Defined Names

([This answer](https://superuser.com/a/218106/542697) shows where to go in Excel to access defined names/named ranges.)

**1st Name:  `wsNamesArray`**

```
=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1))) & T(NOW())
```

**2nd Name:  `wsName`**

```
=MID(CELL("filename", INDIRECT("A1")),FIND("]",CELL("filename",INDIRECT("A1")))+1,255) & T(NOW())
```

*(Part of the formula, `&T(NOW()` doesn't change the result, but it makes the formula "volatile" which causes Excel to recalculate it after any change.  This makes the formula update immediately after a sheet is renamed.)*

### Formulas

Now that you have created the defined names, you can use the following formulas in any cell:

**Previous Sheet**

```
=IF(  MATCH(wsName,wsNamesArray,0)-1 =0, ERROR.TYPE(7), INDEX(wsNamesArray,MATCH(wsName,wsNamesArray,0)-1))
```

**Next Sheet**

```
=IF(  MATCH(wsName,wsNamesArray,0)=wsCount, ERROR.TYPE(7), INDEX(wsNamesArray,MATCH(wsName,wsNamesArray,0)+1))
```

**First Sheet**

```
=INDEX(wsNamesArray,1) & T(NOW())
```

**Last Sheet**

```
=INDEX(wsNamesArray,COUNTA(wsNamesArray)) & T(NOW())
```

**This Sheet**

```
=wsName
```

**2nd Sheet** (note the 2 in the formula)

```
=INDEX(wsNamesArray,2) & T(NOW())
```

**3rd Sheet** (note the 3 in the formula)

```
=INDEX(wsNamesArray,3) & T(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=EOMONTH([worksheet reference],SHEET()-1)
```

First sheet in one workbook is named "Jan" with the date I reference in cell J4, so all J4 cells in subsequent worksheets use

```
=EOMONTH(Jan!J4,SHEET()-1)
```

First sheet in another workbook starts with "Apr" so each subsequent J4 cell has

```
=EOMONTH(Apr!J4,SHEET()-1)
```